# Erro "too many values to unpack" no modelo Gradient Boosting Regressor

Tags: python, machine-learning

Estou utilizando o modelo *GradientBoostingRegressor* para prever uma variável de vendas, porém quando executo o código abaixo apresenta um erro.

Segue o código:

```
# Definindo a escala
escala_f = StandardScaler().fit(X_treino)
reescala_f = escala_f.transform(X_treino)

# Utilizar outros valores de estimador ("padrão é 100").
valores_grid = dict(n_estimators = np.array([50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400]))

# Criando o modelo
modelo = GradientBoostingRegressor(random_state = 7)

# Definindo k
kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=None, shuffle=False)

# Testando a combinação de parâmetros
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = modelo, param_grid = valores_grid, 
                    cv = kfold, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error')
grid_result = grid.fit(reescala_f, Y_treino)

# Exibe o parametro com melhor MSE 
# ***********************
print("Melhor MSE: %f utilizando %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
for params, mean_score, scores in grid_result.cv_results_:
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (scores.mean(), scores.std(), params))
```

O erro é esse:

> ```
> 26 print("Melhor MSE: %f utilizando %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
> ---> 27 for params, mean_score, scores in grid_result.cv_results_:
> 28     print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (scores.mean(), scores.std(), params))
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro ocorre porque o método cv_results_ retorna uma lista de **dicionários**, em vez de uma lista de **tuplas**, e você está tentando desempacotar cada elemento como se fossem 3 valores `(params, mean_score, scores)`.

Para corrigir isso, você precisa acessar as chaves dos dicionários individualmente ao percorrer a lista. Por exemplo:

```
for result in grid_result.cv_results_:
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (result["mean_test_score"], result["std_test_score"], result["params"]))
```

Isso vai imprimir o que você quer sem erro.

Observe que a chave para o valor de score médio do teste é "mean_test_score" e a chave para o desvio padrão é "std_test_score" e para os parametros é "params".